# How to get memory used by Spark Executor

Tags: apache-spark

I'm trying to understand if our memory configuration is ok or if we are over-allocating resources in our Executor, but I'm not able to figure out how to get the memory usage.
Note that I've a limitation into getting information via Spark REST API.

What I can see if I extract the details for executor (using http://host:4072/api/v1/applications/app-20201109081013-5073/allexecutors) is (note that I've removed some data for clarity):

```
{
  "id" : "0",
  "hostPort" : "",
  "isActive" : true,
  "memoryUsed" : 50515998177,
  "diskUsed" : 0,
  "maxMemory" : 10119177830,
  "addTime" : "2020-11-09T08:10:15.933GMT",
  "memoryMetrics" : {
    "usedOnHeapStorageMemory" : 50515998177,
    "usedOffHeapStorageMemory" : 0,
    "totalOnHeapStorageMemory" : 10119177830,
    "totalOffHeapStorageMemory" : 0
  }
```

I can understand the `maxMemory` that is basically the allocated memory (10GB of 16GB due to memory region splitting)... but I'm puzzled about the 50GB that I could see as `memoryUsed`.
This seems to be the sum of the storage memory used since the startup as it's always growing...
Same information is shown into Executors tab into Spark UI.

[image: Same information shown into Executor tab into UI]

So the question is: there's a way to get current used storage memory and, last but not least, the same for the execution memory?

Thank you very much